# how to save audio file Text to speech script?

Tags: javascript

I use github.com/unk1911/speech
this for my text to speech application.
all works fine as per application.
Now i want to add feature like save audio file.
how to do it?
the script is like this.

```
<script>
        var pauseResume = 'R';
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#doClear").click(function() {
                $("#taInput").val("");
                return false;
            });

            $("#doPauseResume").click(function() {
                doPauseResume();
                return false;
            });

            $("#doStop").click(function() {
                doStop();
                return false;
            });

            $("#doTTS").click(function() {
                doTTS();
                return false;
            });
        });

        // Initialize speech engine...
        initSpeech();
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Text-To-Speech</h1>
            <center>
                <input type='button' id='doTTS' value='Speak!'/>
                <input type='button' id='doPauseResume' value='Pause/Resume'/>
                <input type='button' id='doStop' value='Stop'/>
                <input type='button' id='doClear' value='Clear'/>
            </center>
        </div>

        <div role="main" class="ui-content">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Cut & Paste Text To Synthesize (or enter a URL)</legend>
                <textarea class='textareaClass' id='taInput' rows="12" cols="50"></textarea><br/>
            </fieldset>
          <div id='statusMsg'></div>

          <div class="option">
            <label for="rate">Voice</label>
            <select id='voice' name='voice'>
            </select>
          </div>
```

how to save text to speech file into folder.
sound is playing perfectly but i want to save the audio file.
please help me.

Comment: What kind of save do you want? online save, where only the website is able to replay the saved audio? or file save, where the user is able to retrieve a file that can be played by an audio player ? If it's a file save, do you have any preference about quality and bandwidth usage?

Comment: i want to save file on web server where this script is running

Comment: A web server that only serve HTML pages isn't enough for that purpose. You need a backend application listening for files that would be sent by the javascript application running in the client's browser

Comment: https://github.com/unk1911/speech

Comment: i use this application

Comment: This is run in the browser, as opposed to on your server. It generates data on the user's computer, and if you did try to send it to your server this one would refuse because it hasn't been configured to accept incoming data other than simple HTTP requests. What you need is a server-side application, coded in maybe PHP, perl, java, python, node.js, that will say "hey, let's listen for data sent to this address, gather a file from that and save it here".

Comment: i am just student at this ground and you give me example for this